# FireDac connection string to FireBird 2.5 embedded

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-xe6, firedac, firebird-embedded

I tried this but it seems it does not work:

```
procedure TDataModule3.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
FDConnection1.Params.Values['Database'] := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'MYDB.fdb' ;
FDConnection1.Params.Add('User_Name=SYSDBA');
FDConnection1.Params.Add('Password=masterkey');
FDConnection1.Params.Add('DriverID=FB');
FDPhysFBDriverLink1.VendorsLib := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) +'fbembed.dll';
  try
     FDConnection1.Open;
     FDTable1.TableName :='mytable';
     FDTable1.Open;
      except
    on E: EDatabaseError do
    ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Any ideas how to make this work ?

Comment: "Does not work" does not tell the reader anything.  Does the ShowMessage execute and what does it say if it does?  If not, what "not working" symptoms do you observe?

Comment: Application opens - no message - table however remains closed.

Comment: Solved... had to copy the firebird folders intl and udf into app folder.

Comment: Either add details to your question and then post your solution as an answer, or delete the question alltogether. As is, this question is of no use to other Stack Overflow users.

Answer (score 1):

Solved... had to copy the firebird folders intl and udf into app folder.